# Python/Selenium "hover-and-click" not working on WebElement whose class changes at hover

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium library on Python to scrape a website written on js. My strategy is moving through the website using selenium and, at the right time, scraping with BeautifulSoup. This works just fine on simple tests, except when, as shown in the following picture,
[I need to click on the "<" button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0kZs.png)

The "class" of the button changes at hover, so I'm using ActionChains to move to the element and click on it (I'm also using sleep to give enough time for the browser to load the page). Python is not throwing any exception, but the click is not working (i.e. the calendar is not moving backwards).

Below I provide the mentioned website and the code I wrote with an example. Do you have any idea why this is happening and/or how can I overcome this issue? Thank you very very much.

Website = https://burocomercial.profeco.gob.mx/index.jsp

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_webdriver)
driver.get('https://burocomercial.profeco.gob.mx/index.jsp') #access website

# Search bar and search button
search_bar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtbuscar"]')
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenido"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button')

# Perform search
search_bar[0].send_keys("inmobiliaria")
search_button.click()

# Select result
time.sleep(2)
xpath='//*[@id="resultados"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/button'
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0].click()

# Open calendar    
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="calI"]').click() #opens calendar
time.sleep(2)

# Hover-and-click on "<" (Here's the problem!!!)
cal_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/div/a') 
time.sleep(4)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(cal_button).perform() #hover
prev_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-prev') #catch element whose class was changed by the hover
ActionChains(driver).click(prev_button).perform() #click
time.sleep(1)
print('clicked on it a second ago. No exception was raised, but the click was not performed')
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hover the <, just click it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_webdriver)
driver.get('https://burocomercial.profeco.gob.mx/index.jsp') #access website

# set up wait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Perform search
driver.find_element_by_id('txtbuscar').send_keys("inmobiliaria")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[alt="buscar"]').click()

# Select result
xpath='//*[@id="resultados"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/button'
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()

# Open calendar    
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'calI'))).click() #opens calendar
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_visible((By.ID, 'ui-datepicker-div'))

# Click on "<"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Ant"]'))).click()
```

A few things

1. If your XPath consists only of an ID, just use `.find_element_by_id()`. It's faster and easier to read.
2. If you are only using the first element in a collection, e.g. `search_bar`, just use `.find_element_*` instead of `.find_elements_*` and `search_bar[0]`.
3. Don't use sleeps. Sleeps are a bad practice and result in unreliable tests. Instead use expected conditions, e.g. to wait for an element to be clickable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the feedback :). However, the last line of the code times out (This exception raises: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ). It seems it's still not getting the "<". Any ideas on why?

Comment: Not sure... I added a wait for the calendar panel to be visible after opening it. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a different approach using requests. I think that Selenium should be the last option to use when doing webscraping. Usually, It is possible to retrieve the data from a webpage emulating the requests made by the web application

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36'}
## Starts session
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers
url_base = 'https://burocomercial.profeco.gob.mx/'
ind = 'index.jsp'
resp0 = s.get(url_base+ind) ## First request, to get the 'name' parameter that is dynamic
soup0 = BS(resp0.text, 'lxml')
param_name = soup0.select_one('input[id="txtbuscar"]')['name']
action = 'BusGeneral' ### The action when submit the form
keyword = 'inmobiliaria' # Word to search
data_buscar = {param_name:keyword,'yy':'2017'} ### Data submitted
resp1 = s.post(url_base+action,data=data_buscar) ## second request: make the search
resp2 = s.get(url_base+ind) # Third request: retrieve the results
print(resp2.text)
queja = 'Detalle_Queja.jsp' ## Action when Quejas selected
data_queja = {'Lookup':'2','Val':'1','Bus':'2','FI':'28-Nov-2016','FF':'28-Feb-2017','UA':'0'} # Data for queja form
## Lookup is the number of the row in the table, FI is the initial date and FF, the final date, UA is Unidad Administrativa
## You can change these parameters to obtain different queries.
resp3 = s.post(url_base+queja,data=data_queja) # retrieve Quejas results
print(resp3.text)
```

With this I got:

```
'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n1|<h2>ABITARE PROMOTORA E INMOBILIARIA, SA DE CV</h2>|0|0|0|0.00|0.00|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0 % |0 % ||2'
```

Which contains the data that is used in the webpage.
Maybe this answer is not exactly what you are looking for, but I think it could be easier for you to use requests.

Comment: This works just perfect! I was using selenium due to my lack of knowledge with js; but your alternative, along with some small changes from my side, will totally serve my purpose. Thank you very much!